# Python: How to refresh the turtle window

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

is there some kind of method to refresh the turtle screen while keeping the turtle drawings and the pen having the same attributes, it's kind of like reloading a page but it still has the same content

Comment: Possible duplicate of:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34033701/python-how-to-reset-the-turtle-graphics-window

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do that
and you can do it by:

```
t = turtle.Turtle()
t.clear()
```