# How to define a draw function for turtle that clears the turtle window before drawing

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I want to define a function that draws a shape using turtle graphics. I want the function to be able to clear the turtle graphics window once it is called again. Is there a way to do this or a way that  I can close the turtle window once it's done and you press a certain key?

This is the function in question:

```
import turtle
import math
turtle
def draw(b, d, w, h):
    bDraw = b*10
    dDraw = d*10
    wDraw = w*10
    hDraw = h*10
    bdAngle = abs(math.atan(dDraw/bDraw)*180/math.pi)
    draw = turtle.Turtle()
    draw
    draw.right(90)
    draw.forward(hDraw)
    draw.left(90)
    draw.forward(wDraw)
    draw.left(90)
    draw.forward(hDraw)
    draw.right(90)
    draw.forward(bDraw)
    draw.left(180-bdAngle)
    draw.forward(math.sqrt(dDraw**2 + bDraw**2))
    draw.left(bdAngle)
    draw.forward(wDraw)
    draw.left(90-(180-bdAngle-90))
    draw.forward(math.sqrt(dDraw**2 + bDraw**2))
    draw.left(180-bdAngle)
    draw.forward(bDraw+wDraw)
```

Comment: use the `clear()` function?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: How to reset the turtle graphics window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34033701/python-how-to-reset-the-turtle-graphics-window)

Answer (score 0):

You have created an instance of `turtle` each time you called the function `draw(b, d, w, h)`.

When initiating a new drawing session, if those turtle instances are no longer needed, call `turtle.clearscreen()` to delete all previous drawings and those turtle instances used to craft the drawings.

```py
def draw(b, d, w, h):
    turtle.clearscreen()
    bDraw = b*10
    # your codes proceed
```

If you'd like to keep those turtle instances for later use, call `turtle.resetscreen()` instead:

```py
def draw(b, d, w, h):
    turtle.resetscreen()
    bDraw = b*10
    # your codes proceed
```